# How to resolved undefined error to a function without adding static library path in eclipse(c,c++)

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gcc, undefined-reference

I have a function, e.g. `add2num` declared and defined in `/dhaneesh/2021_pack/src/` path. I call the `add2num` function from `/dhaneesh/new_pack/src/my_src.c`. After compilation, it returns with error `undefined reference to 'add2num'`. After I added the static library path to eclipse it works fine, but due to memory utilization issues, the client wants to remove all static libraries.

Is there any way to solve this undefined reference error issue without adding a static library?

if yes please help me to solve this issue.

**/dhaneesh/2021_pack/src/my_src.h**

```
/* add2num declaration*/
int add2num(int num1,int num2);
```

**/dhaneesh/2021_pack/src/my_src.c**

```
#include "my_src.h"
.
.
/***Fun definition **/
int add2num(int num1,int num2)
{
    return num1+num2;
}
```

**/dhaneesh/new_pack/src/list.c**

```
#include "my_src.h" 
.
.
.
void myFun()
{
    int a=10,b =20,sum=0;
    sum = add2num(a,b);
    printf("sum =%d\n",sum);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Note: This is a sample code

Comment: You declare `add2num` twice, once in `my_src.h`, and once in `list.c`.
Don't do this. Also, don't use the `extern` keyword here. The inclusion of `my_src.h` is enough.

As for avoiding the "undefined reference" error -  Not too familiar with eclipse, but provided that the results of `my_src.c` and `list.c` get linked together to your final executable, you should not get this error. Are they both in the same "project" in your build?

Comment: Elaborating on why no extern keyword: on functions its use is to [tell the compiler about functions written in other languages](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage)

Comment: Unrelated: You're **missing a return statement** in your `myFun` function.

Comment: thank you for your valid replay, i removed extern keyword  still i face same error, actually my_src.c and list.c are 2 sub project under one main project.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code.

##### Problem 1

You're using the wrong syntax for calling the function `add2num`. In particular, you incorrectly wrote:

```
sum = add2num(int a,int b); //this is not the right syntax to call function add2num
```

##### Problem 2

You're missing a return statement inside function `myFun`.

Additionally, note that there is **no need** for the statement `extern int add2num(int num1,int num2);` inside list.c since you've included the header which have already the function declaration.

---

After removing all these problems, the modified code looks as shown below:

**my_src.h**

```
#ifndef MYSRC_H
#define MYSRC_H
//declaration for add2num
int add2num(int num1,int num2);

#endif
```

**my_src.c**

```
#include "my_src.h"
/***Fun definition **/
int add2num(int num1,int num2)
{
    return num1+num2;
}
```

**my_list.h**

```
#ifndef MYLIST_H
#define MYLIST_H
//declaration for myFun
int myFun();

#endif
```

**my_list.c**

```
#include "my_src.h" 
#include "my_list.h"
#include <iostream>

//definition for myFun
int myFun()
{
    int a=10,b =20,sum=0;
    sum = add2num(a, b);
    std::cout<<"sum: "<<sum<<std::endl;
    return 5; //added this return statement
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/7DP1EFaRL)

Comment: Thank you for your time, actually mysrc.c ,mysrc.h is under /dhaneesh/2021_pack/src/ this  folder and my_list.c and my list.h is under /dhaneesh/new_pack/src/ folder. with static library its work fine but i want to eliminate undefined reference error without adding static library, is it possible

Comment: @Dhaneeshlal.D.R You're welcome. Are you using CMake? How do you compile your project?  I mean which command do you use to build your project. Also, have you tried including full path of the files.

Comment: yes i am using CMake , also i tried with including full path

Comment: @Dhaneeshlal.D.R Ok so if you're using CMake then you must specify all the source files(.cpp files) while building the project. Make sure(if not already) that you've specified `my_list.c` and `my_src.c` files in the list of files inside the CMakeLists.txt. Since in your original question you've not added the CMake file we cannot tell whether if there is anything missing there. The kind of error that you're getting generally happens due to the mentioned reason above.